# ionic custom separator and simple animation

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm actually having a hard time trying to figure this out..

I have a list, which is displayed in a grid. Every 3 elements, there must be a custom separator. Plus, each item has to be animated on :enter.

Problem I'm facing is, the current layout that works for adding that custom separator is the next one:

**HTML markup for custom separator (animates per column... not desired)**

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let row of stampRows"  [@stampsAnimation]="">
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let stamp of row">
          <img [src]="stamp.image">
        </ion-col>

        <!-- empty containers in case row count doesn't get to 3-->
        <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="row.length === 1">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="row.length === 1 || row.length === 2">
        </ion-col>
        <!-- / empty containers -->

        <ion-col col-1 class="divider1" no-padding>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-11 class="divider2" no-padding></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

With this markup, I can add the the separators as needed. But the animations animate per row, no per item.

Now this markup allows me to animate item by item, but I cannot seem to add custom separator (which is made of 2 elements, using 20% and 80% of width).

**HTML markup for working animation (can't add custom separator... not desired)**

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row [@stampsAnimation]="stamps.length">
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let stamp of stamps">
          <img [src]="stamp.image">
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This is the code I'm using for animating:

**Animation code in Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-my-stats',
  templateUrl: 'my-stats.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('stampsAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [

        query(':enter', style({ transform: 'scale(0)' }), { optional: true }),

        query(':enter', stagger('50ms', [
          animate('0.25s ease-in', keyframes([
            style({transform: 'scale(0)'}),
            style({ transform: 'scale(1)'}),
            style({transform: 'scale(1.25)'}),
            style({transform: 'scale(1)'})
          ]))]), { optional: true })
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

As you can see, to build any of those HTML i'm using different arrays, one contains the items directly (stamps[]) and the other is an array containing rows (each row contains 3 items).

**Examples of arrays**

```
stampsRows = [[itemA, itemB, itemC], [itemD, itemE, itemF]];
stamps = [itemA, itemB, itemC, itemD, itemE, itemF];
```

So, I need custom separator, and animate item by item, can someone throw me some light into this?

Thanks for your time!